# Whether to prove Plane, and Line are Perpendicular, or Parallel or Neither

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have the equation a given plane in the format:
$$ax+by+cz+d=0$$
And I have a line in the following format:
$$<a,b,c>+t<d,e,f>$$
I have the normal vector that identifies the plane:
$$\vec{n}=<a,b,c>$$
I have the vector parallel to the line:
$$\vec{v}=<d,e,f>$$
I then take the dot product of the two vectors and get the a non-zero number:
$$\vec{n} \ \cdot \ \vec{v} \ne0$$

From here i can deduce that the plane, and the line are not parallel; however, how do I know if they are not perpendicular?

One observation I have the make is that:
$$\vec{n} = k\vec{v}$$
So since they are scalar multiples of each other are they perpendicular?

Comment: Can you think of any vector that’s perpendicular to the plane? How do you tell when two vectors are parallel?

Comment: @amd $\vec{n}$ is perpendicular to the plane, and the dot product tells when two vectors are parallel

Comment: @amd Because $A \ \cdot B = ||A|| \ ||B|| \cos(\theta)$

Comment: You can instead try solving for the intersection, and based on the outcome, determine the relationship between the two objects.

Comment: You can’t tell from the value of the dot product of two vectors that they’re parallel. Try something else. If I tell you that $u\cdot v=5$, the only thing you can say about $u$ and $v$ is that they’re nonzero and not perpendicular.

Comment: If the normal vector is parallel to the line, dosen't it make the line perpendicular to the plane?